# What is the "Butterick's Practical typography" equivalent for LaTeX?

Tags: luatex, typography, text

As in, is there a manual for how to get good typography using the LaTeX typesetting system that is similar to Matthew Butterick's web-based book? MB's Practical Typography only shows examples for web, MS Word and Pages which is why I'm asking.

That website is linked here: https://practicaltypography.com/

Comment: The [`memoir`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) documentation is really good and contains lots of example designs, not familiar with the book you mentioned but I learnt lots of LaTeX beauty from `memoir` so worth a look

Comment: The good typography depends on the writer and not in the tool.  Underline, for instance,  is bad practice no matter if you are using Word, InDesing, LaTeX or whatever. LaTeX was made with good typography in mind,  so don't be picky the default LaTeX output and probably just that will improve your typography.  Esto es  porque is not easy make many bad practices, as add several spaces manually between words, or several lines between paragraphs, indent incorrectly paragraphs, etc. but, hey,  the foolproof software still is a utopia.

Comment: Do you mean this site https://practicaltypography.com/ ? If so, please add it to your question to stop us from guessing ;-)

Comment: yes, that website.

Comment: I am familiar with practicaltypography.com and the sister site typographyforlawyers.com and have found them to be more or less system agnostic: nowhere does it state that you should / have to / must not use Word, or Indesign, or Framemaker – or LaTeX for that matter. The advice given is sound, it's up to the user to implement it with the tool of their choice.

Comment: What is "good" typography depends not only on the presentation medium (Ebook, web page, PDF, print) but on the nature of the content (professional non-fiction, popular fiction) and the intended readers. Subtle differences in fonts, character spacing, size, and other factors,  make a difference. After looking at Practical Typography, look at the kind of publication you wish to emulate.